# Можно ли употребить словосочетание "вершина радости"?

Tags: словосочетания

Можно ли употребить словосочетание "вершина радости"?. Если нет, то как можно назвать некорректное употребление слов в словосочетании?

Comment: Есть [примеры в религиозных текстах](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E2%E5%F0%F8%E8%ED%E0&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%F0%E0%E4%EE%F1%F2%FC&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=) "вершина радости бытия" или "вершина радости - в принятии воли Божией". Других примеров (не религиозных) Национальный Корпус не приводит.

Answer (score 1):

Радость - это качественное состояние определенного уровня (согласно словарю, чувство удовольствия, ощущение большого душевного удовлетворения). Приставка ДО говорит нам о достижении этого уровня.

Радость бывает маленькой, большой, огромной и беспредельной, так что вершинное состояние нехарактерно для этого чувства.

Но вряд ли можно в этом случае говорить о явной лексической несочетаемости, так как возможно авторское понимание чувства радости как, например,  чувства религиозного блаженства, а выражение "вершина блаженства" вполне легитимное и распространенное.

Answer (score 1):

> Вершина успеха, вершина блаженства... Вершина чего ещё бывает? Пусть
>   форумчане дополнят.

Из **Словаря сочетаемости слов русского языка** под ред. Денисова и Морковкина:

> **ВЕРШИНА** чего-л. *(славы, счастья, знания, искусства…)* -- высшая степень, высший уровень чего-л.

=================

**Из Эдуарда Асадова:**

> *Наверное, это **вершина радости**, удивительная, жаркая, ослепляющая вспышка света. Мгновения и минуты, полярно противоположные минутам
>   горя, отчаяния и тоски. Счастье, как огромный прекрасный алмаз,
>   многогранно.*

Answer (score 0):

Вершина как сильное слово-образ представляется завершением, что с радостью, успехом, блаженством не совсем клеится. Лучше бы подошло слово верх: верх успеха, блаженства, верх мастерства, изящества; вершину радости заменил бы восторгом.

Comment: А верх — это не завершение?

Comment: Верх уровнем, вершина макушкой формы мне представляется.

Comment: Ожегов:
>1. Наиболее высокая, расположенная над другими часть чего-н. В. дома. Жить на самом ~у. До самого (с самого) ~у и ~а. Снять в. дачи.